# números desfasados en etiquetas <ol> (html)

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Estoy haciendo un sitio web   donde  incluyo listas ordenadas
y  me he dado cuenta que los  números en  esas listas se pegan hacia el  borde dejando un gran espacio entre las palabras y los números, como  se muestra en la  imagen:

[image: 1]]

La verdad no sé porqué está sucediendo esto y he revisado desde el html mismo has el javascript sin  encontrar nada raro.

Estoy usando Bootstrap y  jquery

les dejo dos links

1.- de la  página en vivo: https://aloss94.github.io/Nightwish/ 
2.- donde tengo los archivos: https://github.com/AloSs94/Nightwish

Comment: El código necesario debería estar acá en la pregunta y no como un link externo. Por favor visita: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4):

Esto te sucede porque por defecto, los `<ol>` tiene la propiedad `list-style-position: outside;`, con establecerla a `inside` podrías hacer que los números acompañasen al texto en su alineación.

**CSS**

```
#discografia ol {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

**Ejemplo:**

```css
ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Peras</li>
  <li>Manzanas</li>
  <li>Fresas</li>
  <li>Plátanos</li>
  <li>Mangos</li>
  <li>Cerezas</li>
</ol>
```

**Referencia:** [list-style-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position)

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el `.container` del css alinea todo el texto al centro pero no alinea el elemento `<ol>`. Si no quieres complicarte mucho, te recomiendo que le agregues una clase a tu style.css, algo como

```
.listaCanciones{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Y a tus elementos `<li>` les pusieras el numero. Ejemplo:

```
     <ol class="listaCanciones">
         <li id="elv">1. Elvenpath</li>
         <li>2. Beauty and The Beast</li>
         <li>3. The Carpenter</li>
         <li>4. Astral Romance</li>
         <li>5. Angels Fall First</li>
         <li>6. Tutankhamen</li>
         <li>7. Nymphomaniac Fantasia</li>
         <li>8. Know Why The Nightingale Sings</li>
         <li>9. Lappi (Lapland)</li>
       </ol>
```

[image: Ejemplo]

Es algo rudimentario pero es una solución rápida.

Espero que sea de ayuda. Saludos

Comment: y cual sería otra forma?
de todas manera eso me va a yudar muucho